# NEST ElasticSearch, Query Result Is Empty

Tags: elasticsearch, nest

I'm trying to query an elastic search index using a match_all query.

```cs
Uri uri = new Uri("http://10.10.10.67:9200");
ConnectionSettings connection = new ConnectionSettings(uri); 
connection.SetDefaultIndex("leases");
int port = connection.Port;

ElasticClient client = new ElasticClient(connection);

var feeQueryObject = client.Search<FeeQueryResult>(s => s
     .Type("leases").MatchAll());
```

Using sense, I get results but not with NEST.

Not sure if I have to set up my mapped class exactly how the schema is in the ElasticSearch document? - I only have a few properties in my class, not all of them.

Any ideas as to why there are no results returned?

Comment: have you tried with port no 9300..?

Comment: Can you please add your FeeQueryResult mapped class to the question as well.

Comment: You can check the response object's `ConnectionStatus` to find the actual query that was sent to ElasticSearch, which you could then compare against your Sense query to figure out what's causing the difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was my fault.

The type was incorrect. Should be 'fee' not 'leases'.